# Adding fields dynamically to a form after rendering

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm developing a template system for webpages. A template consists of the following properties.

- A name (part of the "template" class)
- Sections (linked to the template class)
- Fields (linked to a section)

It's pretty basic and it works when I got the template all setup in the database itself.
Now I want to create a template in my CMS application. To accomplish this I have rendered a pretty basic formtype form which has the name property of the template.

After the user has entered a name for the template, the user should be able to create sections and fields on the fly(directly from the rendered page itself). To spare me some time I want to ask you if it's possible to attach the sections and fields to the formtype dynamically so Doctrine can pick it up and persist the objects automatically without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a combination of [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) and [Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: I had something similar where I needed to adjust a few fields depending on the user, but was alway using the same entity to modify.  I used a switch statement in the form class and had the user's status as an input to the form.  I easily grabbed that as the case and added a few fields as needed.  This was simple and again used the same entity.  You could use this to grab different forms and use the suggestion above when using a collection.